# Excel VBA On Error Resume Next, Options are correct but still not resuming

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, resume

I have already checked Tools > Options > General > Error Trapping in VBE - I have set it to both "Break in Class Module" and "Break on Unhandled Errors" and either way it still throws the error. The error is thrown on the line:

```
Set xlContacts = Workbooks(LocalContactsFilename)
```

It throws an error saying the subscript is out of range, and I understand that this means the index was not found within the Workbooks collection, this statement is here because usually the file is already open as an addin so I can just get a reference to it through this statement. It is supposed to resume on this error because if the file is not open I open it. 
    One odd thing I noticed about this- even though this line of code is not accessing any remote files or the network, it only throws this error when I am disconnected from the network. If I open the workbook while connected to the network this error is not thrown.
    Has anyone experienced this before? When your options are set to only halt on unhandled exceptions but it halts anyways?

```
Public Sub openContactsFile()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim LocalContactsPath As String
    Dim LocalContactsFilename As String
    Dim LocalContactsShortFilename As String

    LocalContactsPath = wbMyCompanyWorkbook.Names("localContactsPath").RefersToRange.Value
    LocalContactsFilename = Mid(LocalContactsPath, (InStrRev(LocalContactsPath, "\") + 1))
    LocalContactsShortFilename = Mid(LocalContactsFilename, 1, (InStrRev(LocalContactsFilename, ".") - 1))

    'On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not fso.FileExists(LocalContactsPath) Then
        If MsgBox("The contacts file is not available.  Click Yes to update the contacts now, or No to use the workbook without contact auto-fill capability.", vbYesNo, ThisWorkbook.NAME) = vbYes Then
            SyncContacts
        Else
            GoTo cancelParse
        End If
    End If
    If fso.FileExists(LocalContactsPath) Then
        On Error GoTo catch_no_remote_connection
        If fso.GetFile(LocalContactsPath).DateLastModified < fso.GetFile(wbMyCompanyWorkbook.Names("remoteContactsPath").RefersToRange.Value).DateLastModified Then
            If MsgBox("Your local contacts file appears to be out of date, would you like to download the latest contacts file?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion, ThisWorkbook.NAME) = vbYes Then
                SyncContacts
            End If
        End If
catch_no_remote_connection:
        If Err.Number = 53 Then Err.CLEAR
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xlContacts = Workbooks(LocalContactsFilename)

        If xlContacts Is Nothing Then
            Set xlContacts = Workbooks.Open(LocalContactsPath, False, True)
        End If
        xlContacts.Sheets(1).Range("A1:CN2000").Sort Key1:=xlContacts.Sheets(1).Range("F2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=xlContacts.Sheets(1).Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
    End If

    'hide the contacts from view or editing
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Workbooks(LocalContactsFilename) Is Nothing Then xlContacts.IsAddin = True
    Err.CLEAR
    On Error GoTo 0
cancelParse:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: "this statement is here because usually the file is already open as an addin so I can just get a reference to it through this statement" - how about making your code more resiliant? i.e. handle the 2 cases: already open, not already open...

Comment: You cannot set an error handler (even `On Error Resume Next`) while inside another error handler.  Give this a read: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams how did I not know this?! Thank you :). More specifically you might say that you can't set an error handler after an error is raised, but before using a `Resume` to resume normal code execution? I make this distinction because unlike Try/Catch handler code can often be reached by means other than an error, e.g. routine cleanup code.

Comment: Does Err.CLEAR not reset the error handler? I am certain I have used coding just like this before and it worked fine.... in fact this code itself works perfectly fine if I am connected to the network, but throws the error when not connected. -- Why would that make any difference on the line it's throwing?

Comment: Indeed Err.Clear does not reset the Error Handler. You must use Resume or exit the procedure before using the previous or another Error Handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TimWilliams
    Thank you for the answer- I assumed Err.CLEAR resets the error handling but it does not. The code below functions correctly whether connected to the network or not (which I realize now was the origin of the problem), the problem was when it threw the file not found error and went to catch_no_remote_connection, there was no resume to clear the error, so I added this to close out the error handling block and reset the handler:

```
    Resume post_err
post_err:
```

Functional Code:

```
Public Sub openContactsFile()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim LocalContactsPath As String
    Dim LocalContactsFilename As String
    Dim LocalContactsShortFilename As String

    LocalContactsPath = wbMyCompanyWorkbook.Names("localContactsPath").RefersToRange.Value
    LocalContactsFilename = Mid(LocalContactsPath, (InStrRev(LocalContactsPath, "\") + 1))
    LocalContactsShortFilename = Mid(LocalContactsFilename, 1, (InStrRev(LocalContactsFilename, ".") - 1))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not fso.FileExists(LocalContactsPath) Then
        If MsgBox("The contacts file is not available.  Click Yes to update the contacts now, or No to use the workbook without contact auto-fill capability.", vbYesNo, ThisWorkbook.NAME) = vbYes Then
            SyncContacts
        Else
            GoTo cancelParse
        End If
    End If
    If fso.FileExists(LocalContactsPath) Then
        On Error GoTo catch_no_remote_connection
        If fso.GetFile(LocalContactsPath).DateLastModified < fso.GetFile(wbMyCompanyWorkbook.Names("remoteContactsPath").RefersToRange.Value).DateLastModified Then
            If MsgBox("Your local contacts file appears to be out of date, would you like to download the latest contacts file?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion, ThisWorkbook.NAME) = vbYes Then
                SyncContacts
            End If
        End If
catch_no_remote_connection:
        'there is no network connection, clear the error and resume from here
        Err.CLEAR
        Resume post_err
post_err:
        On Error Resume Next
        'get reference to the workbook if it is already open
        Set xlContacts = Workbooks(LocalContactsFilename)

        If xlContacts Is Nothing Then
            'the workbook was not open, open it
            Set xlContacts = Workbooks.Open(LocalContactsPath, False, True)
        End If
        'sort contacts by company, name
        xlContacts.Sheets(1).Range("A1:CN2000").Sort Key1:=xlContacts.Sheets(1).Range("F2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=xlContacts.Sheets(1).Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
    End If

    'hide the contacts from view or editing by setting the workbook as an Addin
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Workbooks(LocalContactsFilename) Is Nothing Then xlContacts.IsAddin = True
    Err.CLEAR
    On Error GoTo 0
cancelParse:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Thank you all for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same (unbelievably frustrating, as far as I can tell inexplicable) problem as you have, but in a different context. I find the best thing to do is to find a work-around. Instead of using error handling as you have, use this instead:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, _
    xlContacts As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name = LocalContactsFilename Then
        Set xlContacts = wb
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb

If xlContacts Is Nothing Then
    Set xlContacts = Workbooks.Open(LocalContactsPath, False, True
End If
```

I would've preferred to code it the way you've done, but it seems there's no choice.

Comment: I have already tried what you are suggesting, the reason this method does not work in this case is because the open workbook's "IsAddIn" property is set to true, so when you iterate through the Workbooks collection it will never find the workbook name.